# Creating a Class 2 circuit using a Class II ac/dc converter

Tags: power-supply, power, safety

I need a Class 2 circuit and I know that I can buy say an off-board DIN mount Class 2 power supply, but I am trying to put everything on a PCB board and looks like all the little converters are class II rated, which is not the same. I've been looking into it and it seems like they are very similar. Is someone familiar with these specific details and know what components I could add to make this Class II unit meet Class 2 requirements? I will be getting this UL inspected after, but if I can  do anything to help meet requirements that would be great.

Any suggestions or recommendations? Thank you.

Here is a small Class II unit I would like to use:(https://www.meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/IRM-10/IRM-10-spec.pdf)

Comment: rather than make us search for what difference you are referring to put the difference you think it is within the question, also tell us what you think they both are so we get a baseline of what you know

Comment: Here is what I know: https://www.cui.com/blog/class-2-vs-class-ii-power-supplies

I am hoping someone who may better know the details than me of these two standards and may know a way to add some components to bring the Class II to meet a Class 2.